# Why does eGit create an extra directory in the remote repo when I do the first commit/push?

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

Using eGit...
When I perform the initial Commit and Push from Eclipse, a new directory appears in the remote repo. Inside that directory is the root of the project directory. It makes a big mess because when someone clones it (again using eGit) the src folder is munged into a name containing then project folder name, which mucks up the package references in the class files.
[image: There is an extra level of directories]

Answer (score 2):

eGit assumes you don't want an entire git repository for a single workspace project. Doing so would be wasteful and cumbersome for almost anything nontrivial. https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Implications

You also didn't commit the `.classpath` file, which would have indicated what the source folders were.

Comment: Would you explain why it's wasteful and cumbersome?

Comment: For nontrivial cases I said, where you have multiple projects. If that means multiple repositories, everything from access control to revision control to builds, and maybe more, gets that much more complicated.